# Plotting color scatterplots matrix

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I`m using RStudio v 0.97. I want to get color scatterplot matrix, here is my code:

```
dt<- impact[c(3,4,7,8)] 
dt.r <- cor(dt)
dt.color <- dmat.color(dt.r)
dt.order<- order.single(dt.r)

cpairs(dt, dt.order, panel.controls = dt.color,  main= "Scatterplots")
```

But my output is black&white scatterplot and warning: "There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)"

How to fix this?

Comment: You've included superfluous information (the version of RStudio), but don't give important information (the packages you use). Also, have you followed the advice and used `warnings()` to see the warnings?

Comment: Where did `impact` and `imp` come from?  Where does `dmat.color` come from? Where does `cpairs` come from? Give us some code we can simply cut and paste to show your problem and then we can help.

Comment: Edit your question and add the relevant `require` or `library` lines. Then create some sample data that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Read the help for cpairs:

```
Usage:

     cpairs(data, order = NULL, 
         panel.colors = NULL, border.color = "grey70", show.points = TRUE, ...)
```

The parameter is `panel.colors` not `panel.controls`.

The warning is a clue - did you read the warning?

```
Warning messages:
1: In plot.window(...) : "panel.controls" is not a graphical parameter
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks it was a problem w dt.color indeed and I`ve already fix this. Thank you very much